# Destroy object when it touch Ground unity 2d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

Hey I just want my bullet to destroy itself when it touch Ground 
i tried to destroy after 2 seconds but it has the same problem 
That's My Code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EnemyBullet : MonoBehaviour
{
    GameObject target;
    public float speed;
    Rigidbody2D bulletRB;

    void Start()
    {
        bulletRB = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        target = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");
        Vector2 moveDir = (target.transform.position - transform.position).normalized * speed;
        bulletRB.velocity = new Vector2(moveDir.x, moveDir.y);
        Destroy(this.gameObject, 2);
    }

    
}
```

Comment: What's the problem with destroying itself after 2 seconds?

Comment: Well this on face value destroys after 2 seconds in assuming your problem was it hadn’t hit the ground?

Comment: @Voidsay it reflect with the ground so the player would damage from a bullet on the ground

Comment: @BugFinder my problem is the bullet hit the ground and be on the ground so i want when it touch the ground it destroy itself

Comment: Right. But as it stands your code has nothing to do with meeting the player in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use OnCollisionEnter() to destroy to bullet

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collider)
{
    if (collider.GameObject.tag == "Ground")
    {
        Destroy (this.GameObject)
    }
}
```

What's happening here is that this function gets called every time it collides with an object, so we put the destroy code here. It takes the collider as a parameter, and then checks if the GameObject has the tag "Ground", and if it does, destroy itself.

Note that you will also have to add a tag to your ground objects in the hiearchy. You can name them anything else too, but make sure to change "Ground" in the code when you do set the tag to anything other than it.

You will probably also have other colliders like walls in your game so you should make a universal tag that destroys bullets and name it something like "Destroy Projectiles" or something.

Edit: You can have multiple functions that destroy the GameObject.

Comment: That's what I need but when I try it i get an error says : This message parameter has to be of type: Collision2D

Comment: Hey Thanks that's Worked Well i just fixed the error by changing Collision to Collision2D

Answer (score 5):

Destroy the bullet object using the Destroy method.The bullet is destroyed after flying a certain distance.

```
 public float speed;
 public float destoryDistance;
 private Rigidbody2D rg2d;
 private Vector3 startPos;
 // Start is called before the first frame update
 void Start()
 {
     rg2d = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
     rg2d.velocity = transform.right * speed;
     startPos = transform.position;
 }

 // Update is called once per frame
 void Update()
 {
     float distance = (transform.position - startPos).sqrMagnitude;
     if (distance > destoryDistance)
     {
         Destroy(gameObject);
     }
 }
```